# Not loading img temporary file on IIS

Tags: image, iis

I have some problem with my IIS today.

I try to load a .img file which is stored on my FTP Server but nothing is loading (red cross).

I verified the path too and it seems to be the good one ... what did I miss ? Any permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something fimilar with another type of file.

You should check around your MIME Type on IIS.

If you don't know what it is, here is a good link to learn it : [MIME Types](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml)

You should try to add .img and see if it is working.